# How to retrieve the absolute path of a file stored inside the jar

Tags: java

I have a file, ("hwc.bat") stored inside of my projects resources folder: "project/res/HWC/hwc.bat".

I am writing code from within a class "/src/test/java/.../aTest.java"

I want to be able to retrieve the absolute path of the file hwc.bat, but using getResource isn't working for me. Here's what I've been trying:

```
final URL resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("hwc.bat");
absolutePath = Paths.get(resource.toURI()).toString();
```

I've tried plenty of variations of "hwc.bat", including things like "/hwc.bat", or "/res/HWC/hwc.bat", but I can't seem to get the URL to be anything but null.

Here is a picture of my project set-up, just to give a better idea of where the file is and what I'm trying to do/the context of everything.

[image: Image of Class Layout]

Comment: pls have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ClassLoader().getResource` only can find resource which are contained in the classpath. This not the case for the current location of your `hwc.bat`.

Since you are using a Maven project, the correct location to place the file is in `src/main/resources` in order to find it via  `ClassLoader.getResource("hwc.bat")`.

Comment: Solution worked. I moved the hwc.bat to src/main/resources/HWC/hwc.bat, and then called `final URL resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("HWC/hwc.bat");` to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

you are using maven structure, so you have to place resource files in src/main/resources